# Nested skewed divs and how can I fill them correctly?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble creating the desired layout I want with CSS and HTML.

What I'm trying to have is a heading skewed div and then have a straight background along the x-axis. Something similar to the image below:

[image: heading sample images]

So far, my attempts have been futile as you can see here. I need the inner div to extend to the full width of the point of the outer div.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: When you say "as you can see here", where is here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hacky version you can use as a starting point:

http://jsfiddle.net/32C6E/1/

It is more complex as you require behind the menu to show the background under the heading. Because of that it requires another element for the white bar after the menu. I've set the white areas to be % width, but the menu isn't so that'd need to be fixed to make sure they never overlap.

The basic technique is to `skewX` the white areas to get the diagonal, and reverse skew the `h1` so that the text is straight. I then add a negative margin to hide the left side of the element.

```
header {
    transform: skewX(-35deg);
    margin-left: -5em
}

header h1 {
    padding: 4em;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(35deg);
}
```

I then absolutely position the menu items so they are in the bottom left corner of the `nav`, and rotate them to the correct angle, with the origin at the bottom left. I then fiddled with the position until the first item was in the correct place:

```
nav li {

    transform: rotate(-55deg);
    transform-origin: bottom left;

    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2.6em;
    left: 0em;
}
```

Finally I selected each menu item individually and added to the left value to poisition them correctly:

nav li:nth-of-type(2) {
      left: 2.5em;
   }

And so on…

Ideally the menu would be kept in the flow of the document so you don't have to manually position each menu item. This is probably possible, but I've run out of time to look into it. I'm sure you can build on it.

Comment: Awarded the answer, this got me started.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try `border-width` property. This will resolve your issue. 
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fBax3/10/)

The HTML:

```
<div class="abc">&nbsp;</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.abc {
    width: 200px;
    height: 0px;
    border-color: lightgray transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 350px 350px 0px 0px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    margin-left:50px;
}
```

Hope this helps.